# Editing mysql data with drop downs

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I have a data entry page where a few drop downs exist. The selected item in the drop down stores in my mysql database with no issue.

I've made a 2nd page to edit individual records. I can display the data from the drop down in a text box with no problem. However, I want to be able to edit the result with the same drop down choices.

I can add the drop down menu on my edit.php page with all the correct options, but the stored value from the database does not appear. Instead I get the first choice by default and not the stored value.

```
<?php
    $position_sql = "SELECT id, position FROM ref_positions ORDER BY position ASC";
    $position_result = mysql_query($position_sql);
        echo "<select name='position'>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($position_result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['position'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
?>
```

I'm using POST and GET to get the correct record ID.

My text boxes, which work fine are as follows:

```
Department:<input type="text" name="department" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[department]"; ?>">
```

I'm assuming I have to build some sort of if statement to display the stored value?

not sure if this helps, but this is my how I grab the ID for the record I want to edit:

```
        <?php
    $id= ($_GET["id"]);


      $sql = "SELECT * FROM people
WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     ?>
```

Entire Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Form Edit Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
$BASE_PATH = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\OGS';
include_once($BASE_PATH . "\includes\layouts\header.php");
?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="subnavigation">
        <?php include_once($BASE_PATH . "\mods\main_menu\index.html");?>
    </div>

  <div id="page"
  <br><br>
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td align=center>Update Employee Information</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
                  <?php 
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('ogs');
?>

        <?php
        $id= ($_GET["id"]);


          $sql = "SELECT * FROM people
    WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
          $result = mysql_query($sql);
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         ?>

          <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>">

            <fieldset>
                <legend><b>Name</b></legend>
                    First Name:<input type="text" name="first_name" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[first_name]"; ?>">
                    Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[last_name]"; ?>">
            </fieldset>
    <br><br>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><b>Contact Information</b></legend>
                    Town:<input type="text" name="town" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[town]"; ?>">
                    Address:<input type="text" name="address" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[address]"; ?>">
                    Province:<input type="text" name="province" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[province]"; ?>">
                    Postal Code:<input type="text" name="postal_code" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[postal_code]"; ?>">
    <br><br>
                    Home Phone:<input type="text" name="home_phone" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[home_phone]"; ?>">
                    Cell Phone:<input type="text" name="cell_phone" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[cell_phone]"; ?>">
            </fieldset>
    <br><br>        
            <fieldset>
                <legend><b>Emergency Contact</b></legend>
                    Emergency Contact Name:<input type="text" name="first_name" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[first_name]"; ?>">
                    Emergency Contact Number:<input type="text" name="last_name" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[last_name]"; ?>">
            </fieldset>
    <br><br>        
            <fieldset>
                <legend><b>Work Information</b></legend>
                    Role:<input type="text" name="role" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[role]"; ?>">
                    Employer:<input type="text" name="company_works_for" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[company_works_for]"; ?>">
    <br><br>
                    Department:<input type="text" name="department" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[department]"; ?>">
                    Position:
                        <?php
    $position_sql = "SELECT id, position FROM ref_positions ORDER BY position ASC";
    $position_result = mysql_query($position_sql);
    echo "<select name='position'>";

    // You should use PHP to get the existing value here, I have made it up here as 14
    $existing_id = '$row[id]';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($position_result))
    {
        // Check if the existing id is the same as the current id we are displaying
        // If it is, set the selected attribute
        if($existing_id == $row['id'])
            echo "<option selected='selected' value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['position'] . "</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['position'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>  

    <br><br>
                    Is Supervisor?:
                            <input type="radio" name="is_supervisor" value="<?php echo "$row[is_supervisor]"; ?>"> Yes
                            <input type="radio" name="is_supervisor" value="<?php echo "$row[is_supervisor]"; ?>"> No
    <br><br>        
                    Is Active?:
                            <input type="radio" name="active_employee" value="<?php echo "$row[active_employee]"; ?>"> Yes
                            <input type="radio" name="active_employee" value="<?php echo "$row[active_employee]"; ?>"> No
    <br><br>
                    Start Date:<input type="text" name="start_date" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[start_date]"; ?>">
            </fieldset>


                <input type="submit"
              name="submit value" value="Update">

          </form>




      </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The record for Nicholas Furlong shows him as a Health & Safety Coordinator.
http://prntscr.com/3o34g2

But when I click edit, and go to my edit page, it has him listed as controller. (This is the first option in the column.)
http://prntscr.com/3o36qu

Comment: basic html: if you want an `<option>` to be the "already selected" option, then you need to put in a `selected="selected"` attribute.

Comment: it would have to select the stored value in the mysql database though, wouldnt I need php to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what you are asking. But I will try

```
<?php
    $position_sql = "SELECT id, position FROM ref_positions ORDER BY position ASC";
    $position_result = mysql_query($position_sql);
    echo "<select name='position'>";

    // You should use PHP to get the existing value here, I have made it up here as 14
    $existing_id = 14;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($position_result))
    {
        // Check if the existing id is the same as the current id we are displaying
        // If it is, set the selected attribute
        if($existing_id == $row['id'])
            echo "<option selected='selected' value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['position'] . "</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['position'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Im trying to edit information from table1. 

This is done in my edit.php file.

One of the drop down menus in edit.php has information stored in table2.

Im using the id from table1 to populate everything, including the stored value for the drop down. However, I want to be able to edit the drop down choice with the choices available from table2.

Comment: `$existing_id = '$row[id]';` is wrong. You should use `$existing_id = $row[id];` The quotes turn it into a string so it won't execute as code. Do you mean, as an example, you have a country in your first drop down, then the second drop down has all the countries in that are within the country from the 1st drop down?

Comment: No, im not trying to make it conditional or anything.

I have a list of positions that are predefined in table2. 

Table1 contains information on an employee, including their position. 

So if an employee changed position I want to be able to select from the predefined list of positions. (Which is held in a different table)

Comment: added two images to my post to hopefully illustrate what I mean.